# Product Flavors duplicate class error

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I followed the docs instruction, also similar SO answers but I still get a duplicate class error for ClassA.java when I try to build and run.

I have classes used by both flavors in main source set and every class that has a different impl, between different flavors, in free or pro source sets (not in main).

Any suggestions???

project dir structure:

```
project/
   |
   |---src/
        |---free/
        |      |
        |      |---java/
        |      |     |---com.abc
        |      |              |---innerpkg
        |      |                 |-----classA.java
        |      |---res/
        |      |---AndroidManifest.xml
        |
        |---main
        |      |
        |      |---java/
        |      |     |---com.abc
        |      |              |-----classC.java
        |      |              |-----classD.java
        |      |---res/
        |      |    |---drawable/
        |      |    |---layout/
        |      |    |---values/
        |      |         
        |      |---AndroidManifest.xml
        |
        |---pro/
        |      |
        |      |---java/
        |      |     |---com.abc
        |      |              |---innerpkg
        |      |                 |-----classA.java
        |      |---res/
        |      |---AndroidManifest.xml
```

Gradle file:

```
...
android {
    ...

    flavorDimensions "flavor" // changes to one dimension instead of: flavorDimensions "free","pro"
    productFlavors {
        free {
            dimension "flavor"
            applicationId "com.abc"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.configFree
        }
        pro {
            dimension "flavor"
            applicationId "com.abc.pro"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.configPro
       }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/jniLibs"
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        free {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/free/java']
            manifest.srcFile "src/free/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
        pro {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/pro/java']
            manifest.srcFile "src/pro/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the `flavorDimensions`, once I set a single dimension for both flavors I could place the same filename in each respective source set.

Then I just needed to change the build Variant to the one I want to work on it.

I wasted a few hours on this...

Hopefully this might save someone else those lost hours

Answer (score 0):

You can have a module common which contains common classes used in both modules/flavors. That will avoid this problem.

Comment: How will this help? I need different versions of the same class.
Also I have no problem with "shared" classes, I just place them in main source set

Answer (score 0):

You can create a abstract class in main src directory and in your product flavours, implement this class. 
Now you will have different Implementations of same class

Comment: thanks but that won't accomplish what I'm trying to do, I need the the same class name so different flavors will use the same class but each flavor will use it in a slightly different manner.
Also it clearly says in the docs (and other SO answers): " you can have each build type define its own version of the file and not include it in the main/ source set".
I want it to work this way (that how it is suppose to be impl) and not with some workaround

Comment: When you will have an abstract class it will be common across all your flavours. It's concrete implementation of a particular method will make it do different works like you need.
I don't think this is a workaround, this is one of the ways of doing it. 
Or may be I misunderstood the question